# Can i assume that local id is equal to global id for the first workgroup in OpenCL on all platforms

Tags: opencl

Can i assume that `get_local_id(0)` is equal to `get_global_id(0)` for the first work group in OpenCL on all hardware/platforms?

The question is about, if every work-item spawned are given id `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7` in global space and then `0,1,2,3 | 0,1,2,3` in local space.

Alternative it could be local space, `0,2,4,6 | 1,3,5,7`. where | splits the two workgroups in this example of two workgroups and 8 work items.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is described in section 3.2 (Execution model) of the [OpenCL 1.2 specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf), but not referenced later in section 6.12.1 (Work-item functions).

```
global_id(d) = global_offset(d) + local_id(d) + group_id(d) * local_size(d)
global_size(d) = local_size(d) * num_groups(d)
```

If global_offset is (0,0,0), your assumption is correct.

Comment: thanks. Didnt read that part. But from specs: global_offset Must currently be a NULL value when using en..NDkernel.

Comment: I'm not sure this restriction still applies to OpenCL 1.2.

Comment: Okay. One more comment, i asked because i am looking in to coalesced memory access. But what if all my work items need access to global memory m[0] at the same time. (all the local_id of each work group). will they be waiting for eachother to get the memory or will it load that one item into each workitem fast. Alternative i could shift all  by 1 such each work item access a coalesced item?

Comment: Broadcasting the same value to all work-items is usually implemented, and is fast. Especially with GPU, tuning the code requires profiling and benchmarking.